# Zend Framework DB Select doesn't get the data for the whole row

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I'm stumped.

I have a set of databases which hold client data, stuff like personal details in, say, client_personal, and contact details in client_contact, etc. There are 6 joins going on here to collect a full row of information. So, logically (or so I thought), I did this;

```
$oSelect->from(array('details' => 'client_details'))
        ->joinLeft(array('contact' => 'client_contact'), 'contact.client_id = details.id')
        ->joinLeft(array('other'   => 'client_other_details'), 'other.client_id = details.id')
        ->joinLeft(array('nok'     => 'client_nextofkin'), 'nok.client_id = details.id')
        ->joinLeft(array('notes'   => 'client_notes'), 'notes.client_id = details.id')
        ->joinLeft(array('contract' => 'client_contract'), 'contract.client_id = details.id')
        ->joinLeft(array('image'   => 'client_image'), 'image.client_id = details.id')
        ->where('details.id = ?', $cid);
```

Now, this returns a good amount of information, but it's lacking some fields in my test data. For instance, client_contact contains:

```
id    client_id    email    phone    mobile    phone    address    postcode    country
```

And while I've verified that all the fields hold some test data, I'm getting the data for every field except "phone" and "address" - phone is a varchar(11) field, identical to mobile, which I'm getting the data out of, and address is a text field, identical to postcode (for the purpose of this test) which I'm also getting the data for.

It's not getting lost along the way - a var_dump() immediately after running `->fetch()` shows that it's just not getting the data out of the database. I dumped the statement this code produces and ran that myself, and got data in all the rows.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. What was happening here was related to the content of two tables - client_details, and client_nextofkin.

Both tables held fields labelled "address" and "phone", and since the next of kin table came into the join after the contact details table, those fields were overwritten in my resultset.